# Improving frmware for controlling robotic arm via ROS

Tags: res-noetic

I have a robotic arm driven by regular "hobby" servos. It is driven by a teensy which in turn is connected to a Rasberry Pi running ROS.

The teensy will receive high level commands (like "park" or "open claw") via rosserial. The code on the teensy converts the request to a series of commands to the servo to change its position.

If I direct the servo in one shot to the desired angle it moves way too fast. So I divide up the needed motion into steps computed by a linear interpolation relative to the time I want it to take.

I am experimenting with different algorithms but so far the motion is slow enough but really jerky and ugly. What techniques are there to smooth out the motion for these kinds of servos? I would really appreciate any help, links, pointers, packages or other! Thanks!

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/smooth-servo-control-library#29970

Answer (score 2):

If you integrate your robot with [MoveIt](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html), you will get trajectory planning "for free" with a whole suite of different planning plugins that can create very pretty-looking trajectories using quintic spline interpolation.

The "catch" is that in order to integrate with MoveIt, you will need to implement a Robot Hardware interface, which is poorly documented (you can see [my working implementation](https://github.com/01binary/str1ker/blob/master/src/hardware.cpp), and the [official example](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/ros_control_boilerplate)).

I think you have two choices:

- Integrate with MoveIt, which will require you to have a robot description (URDF), 3D models of your robot links, inverse kinematics plugin generated by using IKFast, and a Robot Hardware Interface running on the Raspberry Pi that will communicate with Teensy, which will then talk to the servos. If you are serious about robotics (i.e. your primary goal is to learn) then I would recommend this path.
- Rip the [code](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_planners/chomp/chomp_motion_planner/src/chomp_trajectory.cpp#L143) that interpolates trajectory start/end points with Quintic Splines out of MoveIt and use it directly on the Teensy. This is fairly simple and the least amount of work to get a fun result, but you'll miss out on learning and real robotics experience. I had to rip that code out myself as a matter of fact (for a different reason), see [interpolateQuntic](https://github.com/01binary/str1ker/blob/master/src/plannerPlugin.cpp#L228) method here. Once you have the interpolated trajectory you also need a way to "play it back", you can see an example of how that can be done in my robot's [MoveIt trajectory controller](https://github.com/01binary/str1ker/blob/master/src/trajectoryController.cpp#L519).